# change types, from none type to integer

Tags: python, python-3.x, types, nonetype

I am new to python, and I am trying to write a program which solve second degree equation.

The problem is that I can't add an integers to a none-type variable, there for I have decided to change none-type variable into an integer, but I couldn't. I tried many times but without success.

This is the code:

```
# MY FIRST PROJECT

import math

a = 1
b = -4
c = 1

D = b**2-4*a*c
print(D)

Z=print("the square root of D is: %f" % math.sqrt(D))
print(type(Z))

if D < 0:
 print("the problem can't be solved in R because D is negative")

if D == 0 :
 x = print(-b/2*a)

if D > 0:
 print("the problem has two solutions")
 y = print((-b+Z)/2*a)
 k = print((-b-Z)/2*a)
```

The error which I keep getting is:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is caused by:

```
Z=print("the square root of D is: %f" % math.sqrt(D))
```

[`print` is a function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) which always returns `None` (like all functions with no meaningful value to return; omitting or bypassing a `return` from a user-defined function implicitly returns `None` as well), so `Z` is always `None`. If the goal is to assign the square root of `D` to `Z`, replace it with:

```
Z = math.sqrt(D)
print("the square root of D is: %f" % Z)
```

That code should be moved *after* the block handling `if D < 0:` though, as `math.sqrt` will raise a `ValueError` if it is provided a negative input.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The problem has been solved. Much appreciated